# How to filter android logcat messages and stored in internal memory

Tags: android, filter, logcat

I am creating android application that consists of log cat details. log cat messages were fetched and was stored in a file in the internal storage.But the data was storing in a file was not in order that was showing in log cat.Here, i want to store data in a ordered manner and i want to filter messages from log cat.Is it possible to filter messages from log cat . Can anyone tell me how to filter messages from logcat and store as text file in internal memory

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] cmd = new String[] { "logcat", "-f", "/sdcard/myfilename", "-v", "time", "ActivityManager:W", "myapp:D" };
```

If it fails, write the complete path `/system/bin/logcat`, remember that you may need to include this permissions into AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
```

I hope that it helps you.

Comment: My app was not responding with your code dude @DaSound

Comment: Im Sorry guy , I forgot add the final line: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

Comment: i did it but my application not responds with your code.

Comment: Mmmmm, so curious, it works for me. Did you tried with absolute path? May be an error ocurred while accessing to this path. The app not responds or shows a FC?